# How to display website only if its above a certain resolution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm assuming there is a pretty simple solution to this but I'm very new to javascript/jquery. I'm making a project and what I have to do is make it not display if it's below 1366x768 resolution. I know using jquery and java script you can get the resolution of the browser/monitor but I'm clueless how to make it not display if its lower than 1366x768.

Any way for it to hide the  tag?

Thank you

Comment: By "not display" you mean that there should only be a visible div like "This website does not support resolution less than YxZ", like hide the entire body element of the html?

Comment: Use CSS Media queries for this, not JS. Although it's a very odd requirement. Restricting access to a site based on resolution hasn't really been a thing since the 90s. With the advent of responsive layouts there is no good reason for this any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a class and append it inside a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) like the one below:

```
@media only all and (max-width:1366px) { 
    .siteContentContainer{
        display:none;
    }

    .siteWidthNotSupported{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Add the class siteContentContainer to your body or whatever root element you want to hide, and add the other class to a container with an appropriate message to warn users

Answer (score 0):

With jquery it could be `$( "html" ).empty();`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. First check display width and dimensions then choose from two methods provided. Method 1 adds an css overlay over the page, while method 2 removes the content of the body after the page load

```
if ($(window).width() < 1366) && $(window).height() < 768) ) {
//Method 1
$("body").append('<div id="overlay" style="background-color:#ffffff;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;z-index:999"></div>');
//Method 2
$("body").empty();

}
else {
console.log('size okay');
}
```

or you can just use CSS Media Queries, but since you're asking how to do in JS/jQuery, here it is

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do such a thing:

```
if(window.screen.availWidth < 1366 && window.screen.availHeight < 768) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML("You cannot view the page");
}
```